# How to check if a text input string on change has a Lowercase letter Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if a text input, on change, has a lowercase letter, in the string using just javascript (or in combination with regex)?

*For example:*

```
const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");
passwordInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.value does not contain a lowercase letter) {
        console.log("Must contain a lowercase letter.")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the current value with an upper cased value. If it's equal you don't have lower case letters.

```
const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");

passwordInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.value === e.target.value.toUpperCase()) {
        console.log("Must contain a lowercase letter.")
    }
})
```

If you want to use a RegExp:

```
const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");
const lowerCaseRegExp = /[a-z]+/;

passwordInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (!lowerCaseRegExp.test(e.target.value)) {
        console.log("Must contain a lowercase letter.")
    }
})
```